# Java Looking for jdk that has a deprecated method close_statements()

Tags: java, oracle10g

I am maintaining and application that uses Oracle Moble Database 10.2.0.1.1 and several MDUs.  This has been in place for about 16 years.  Everything worked fine up until about a week ago when we started having syncing issues.  If an MDU fails to sync three times, it schedules a full refresh of the data, which can take up to two hours.  While this is happening, it's causing other MDUs trying to sync to time out.  And the list of MDUs that require full refreshes grows, so forth and so on.

We've dug around and found that the cause seems to be an error of the application trying to find a method to close the current session with the database.  As such, it causes a time out.  I've looked on Google, here, and even on Oracle's deprecated pages and I can't find anything.  We've changed nothing, no new code, no switching of the jdk/jre, but we're wondering if perhaps something was corrupted, or something else.  So I'm trying to find this method so we can try installing a jdk/jre that has it and see if it resolves the issue.  The message from the stack trace is below:

```
clog: : MANDATORY: ALL: Exception in cycle: 
  Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock

  ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock
```

clog: : MANDATORY: ALL: 
      Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.close_statements()
      oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.close_statements()